# Can I extend escape codes for Active Process Name in Title Bar that work locally to also work when I ssh to another machine?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I don’t yet understand the escape codes to set the "Active process name" in OS v10.14.6 Terminal.app's title bar.

So far, I understand how to use the following escape  codes per documentation settings for "Document" and "Working Directory" and appreciate any guidance if I'm understand this part correctly:

Settings:
[image: Terminal Profile Window Settings]
Escape codes per Mac OS:
[image: Escape Codes per Apple]

1. Display working directory in titlebar, clear document first.

   $ echo -n -e "\033]6;\007\c" && echo -n -e "\033]7;file:/etc;\007\c"

Works as expected.

[image: working directory]

(which will display working directory, however it gets replaced quickly by some other script which I think Apple owns)

2. Display document in titlebar, clear working directory first.

$ echo -n -e "\033]7;\007\c" && echo -n -e "\033]6;file:/etc/passwd;\007\c"
[image: document]

Works as expected.

3. Enable "Active process name" and "Arguments" so I can see which process is invoked in the terminal session:
   [image: Active Process]

[image: Active Process working]

Active process "bash" shows as expected, however I'm unsure how to set this via escape codes.  I would like to update the active process name when I "ssh" into other systems.

Is there a guide or trick to setting this via ssh to other systems?

PARTIAL SOLUTION: I figured out a way to get the process name via Bash printed.  Although not a complete solution it is to include this in .promptrc or .bashrc.  The \033]2 is required vs \033]0:

```
trap 'printf "\033]2;%s\007" "${BASH_COMMAND//[^[:print:]]/}" >&2' DEBUG

$ printf "\033]7;file:/etc\007"
```

seems to update the working directory, but it seems like there is some other script maybe Apple Mac OSX is running that overwrites what I see only temporarily in the title bar.

UPDATE:

I also found that the Apple Terminal.app runs in a loop executing this file, which does some of the work to get the pathname in the title bar:

```
   /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal
```

Comment: Assuming you’re in bash - look for PROMPT_COMMAND and a function settitle for looking into how `cd` changes this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/5080670#5080670

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below and accept it.